# I can only print e[i] and nothing else. Even when I comment the line out it still gets printed, but no other print calls work

Tags: python, printing

Here is my code. I am trying to implement an Ensemble Kalman Filter, and at the moment I am trying to check the shapes of my matrices. I put print calls inside of the filter's methods. I also have tried the code below, but the only thing that ever prints is error[i]. Even when I comment out the line it still prints the error. My class doesn't have a print call in it at all anymore, but I can't figure out why the error is printing regardless. Help.

```
for i in range(2):
    print(i)
    print(filt.K.shape)
    filt.predict()
    filt.means[i] = filt.update(obs[i])
    e[i] = rmse_s(filt.x, real[i])
    print(e[i])
```

Comment: Please indent your code correctly. It sounds a little incredible that you're still seeing something printed if your code doesn't print it. Are you sure you're running the correct file? Look for all `print`s in the code to see if it could be coming from elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that another file was running because of my import statement.